# Limit permissions on entities used by custom WCF data service method

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm building a simple public `WCF` Service for a company that provides ISO certifications. Goal is to integrate the service to their public website so that it's possible to query for a company name or certification ID and see the matching certifications. I created the following two custom methods for that purpose:

1. GetByCompany(string query) returns all certifications of the single company that matches query (is limited to one company).
2. GetByCertId(string query) returns certificate and corresponding company matching with query.

The data is stored in a single entity called Certificates. I only want my two custom methods to be accessible publicly but in order for them to access Certificates I have to grant read access to Certificates too - which defeats the purpose of my custom methods (see [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788(v=vs.110).aspx), Note at Service Operations Access Control). I've set permission like this:

```
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetByCompany", ServiceOperationRights.ReadMultiple);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetByCertId", ServiceOperationRights.ReadMultiple);
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Certificates", EntitySetRights.ReadMultiple);
```

> How can I restrict access to certificates but still use custom methods
>   to return the results I need?